# How to disable and enable table row based on check box?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to disable all the table row based on the notcoverd checkbox click and enable the table row if any single notcoverd checkbox is clicked. The function which i have written is working properly except single checkbox uncheck.

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <span class="chkBoxcls">
      <input id="chkboxIP" class="chkBoxPer" style="text-align: center" type="checkbox" name="checkBoxPercent" value="1">
    </span>
  </td>
  <td style="text-align:left" class="txtPer">
    <strong id="lbl1">Inpatient(IP)</strong><button class="btn btn-sm hide arrowNone"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
  </td>

  <td>
    <asp:TextBox id="IINTier1Ip" CssClass="TxtBox12 txtDataPopTier1 clearValueIp" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span15" runat="server" class="pers">%</span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="IINTier2Ip" CssClass="TxtBox12 txtDataPopTier2 clearValueIp" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span16" runat="server" class="pers">%</span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="OONIp" CssClass="TxtBox12 txtDataPopOON clearValueIp txtIpOon" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span17" runat="server" class="pers">%</span>
  </td>

  <td>
    <span class="chkBoxcls">
      <input id="chkNotCoveredIp" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CheckBox1" class="chkNotCovIp">
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="hidden toggle advanced"">
  <td>
    <span class="chkBoxcls">
      <input id="chkboxIpMedical" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CheckBox1">
    </span>
  </td>
  <td style="text-align:left"><span style="padding-left: 3%">IP Medical</span></td>
  <td>
    <asp:TextBox id="IINTier1IpMedical" CssClass="TxtBox12 txtDataPopTier1 clearValueIpMed clearValueIp" onInput="computeValue('#IINTier1IpMedical','#IINTier2IpMedical','#OONIpMedical')" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span18" runat="server" class="pers">%</span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="IINTier2IpMedical" CssClass="TxtBox12 txtDataPopTier2 clearValueIpMed clearValueIp" onInput="computeValue('#IINTier1IpMedical','#IINTier2IpMedical','#OONIpMedical')" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span19" runat="server" class="pers">%</span>
  </td>

  <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="OONIpMedical" CssClass="TxtBox12 txtDataPopOON clearValueIpMed txtIpOon clearValueIp" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span20" runat="server" class="pers">%</span>
  </td>

  <td>
    <span class="chkBoxcls">
      <input id="chkNotCoveredIpMedical" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CheckBox1" class="chkNotCovIp">
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="hidden toggle advanced">
  <td>
    <span class="chkBoxcls">
      <input id="chkboxIpSurgical" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CheckBox1">
    </span>
  </td>
  <td style="text-align:left"><span style="padding-left: 3%">IP Surgical</span> </td>
  <td>
    <asp:TextBox id="IINTier1IpSurgical" CssClass="TxtBox12 txtDataPopTier1 clearValueIpSur clearValueIp" onInput="computeValue('#IINTier1IpSurgical','#IINTier2IpSurgical','#OONIpSurgical')" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span21" runat="server" class="pers">%</span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="IINTier2IpSurgical" CssClass="TxtBox12 txtDataPopTier2 clearValueIpSur clearValueIp" onInput="computeValue('#IINTier1IpSurgical','#IINTier2IpSurgical','#OONIpSurgical')" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span22" runat="server" class="pers">%</span>
  </td>

  <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="OONIpSurgical" CssClass="TxtBox12 txtDataPopOON clearValueIpSur txtIpOon clearValueIp" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span23" runat="server" class="pers">%</span>
  </td>

  <td>
    <span class="chkBoxcls">
      <input id="chkNotCoveredIpSurgical" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CheckBox1" class="chkNotCovIp">
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="hidden toggle advanced">
  <td>
    <span class="chkBoxcls">
      <input id="chkboxIpMeternity" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CheckBox1">
    </span>
  </td>
  <td style="text-align:left"><span style="padding-left: 3%">IP Maternity</span> </td>
  <td>
    <asp:TextBox id="IINTier1IpMaternity" CssClass="TxtBox12 txtDataPopTier1 clearValueIpMet clearValueIp" onInput="computeValue('#IINTier1IpMaternity','#IINTier2IpMaternity','#OONIpMaternity')" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span24" runat="server" class="pers">%</span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="IINTier2IpMaternity" CssClass="TxtBox12 txtDataPopTier2 clearValueIpMet clearValueIp" onInput="computeValue('#IINTier1IpMaternity','#IINTier2IpMaternity','#OONIpMaternity')" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span25" runat="server" class="pers">%</span>
  </td>

  <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="OONIpMaternity" CssClass="TxtBox12 txtDataPopOON clearValueIpMet txtIpOon clearValueIp" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span26" runat="server" class="pers">%</span>
  </td>

  <td>
    <span class="chkBoxcls">
      <input id="chkNotCoveredIpMeternity" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CheckBox1" class="chkNotCovIp">
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="hidden toggle advanced">
  <td>
    <span class="chkBoxcls">
      <input id="chkboxIpMHSA" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CheckBox1">
    </span>
  </td>
  <td style="text-align:left"><span style="padding-left: 3%">IP MHSA</span></td>
  <td>
    <asp:TextBox id="IINTier1IpMHSA" CssClass="TxtBox12 txtDataPopTier1 clearValueIpMhsa clearValueIp" onInput="computeValue('#IINTier1IpMHSA','#IINTier2IpMHSA','#OONIpMHSA')" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span27" runat="server" class="pers">%</span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="IINTier2IpMHSA" CssClass="TxtBox12 txtDataPopTier2 clearValueIpMhsa clearValueIp" onInput="computeValue('#IINTier1IpMHSA','#IINTier2IpMHSA','#OONIpMHSA')" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span28" runat="server" class="pers">%</span>
  </td>

  <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="OONIpMHSA" CssClass="TxtBox12 txtDataPopOON clearValueIpMhsa txtIpOon clearValueIp" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span29" runat="server" class="pers">%</span>
  </td>

  <td>
    <span class="chkBoxcls">
      <input id="chkNotCoveredIpMHSA" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CheckBox1" class="chkNotCovIp">
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="hidden toggle advanced">
  <td>
    <span class="chkBoxcls">
      <input id="chkboxIpNICU" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CheckBox1">
    </span>
  </td>
  <td style="text-align:left"><span style="padding-left: 3%">IP NICU</span> </td>
  <td>
    <asp:TextBox id="IINTier1IpNICU" CssClass="TxtBox12 txtDataPopTier1 clearValueIpNicu clearValueIp" onInput="computeValue('#IINTier1IpNICU','#IINTier2IpNICU','#OONIpNICU')" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span30" runat="server" class="pers">%</span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="IINTier2IpNICU" CssClass="TxtBox12 txtDataPopTier2 clearValueIpNicu clearValueIp" onInput="computeValue('#IINTier1IpNICU','#IINTier2IpNICU','#OONIpNICU')" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span31" runat="server" class="pers">%</span>
  </td>

  <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="OONIpNICU" CssClass="TxtBox12 txtDataPopOON clearValueIpNicu txtIpOon clearValueIp" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span32" runat="server" class="pers">%</span>
  </td>

  <td>
    <span class="chkBoxcls">
      <input id="chkNotCoveredIpNICU" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CheckBox1" class="chkNotCovIp">
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

js file

```
    //select all checkboxes
    $("#chkNotCoveredIp").change(function () {  //"select all" change 
        $(".chkNotCovIp").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked")); //change all ".checkbox" checked status
        $(".clearValueIp").prop("disabled", false);
        $(".clearValueIp").val('');
    });

    //".checkbox" change 
    $('.chkNotCovIp').change(function () {
        //uncheck "select all", if one of the listed checkbox item is unchecked
        if (false == $(this).prop("checked")) { //if this item is unchecked
           
            $(".clearValueIp").prop("disabled", false); // 
        }
        //check "select all" if all checkbox items are checked
        if ($('.chkNotCovIp:checked').length == $('.chkNotCovIp').length) {
            $("#chkNotCoveredIp").prop('checked', true);
            $(".clearValueIp").prop("disabled", true);
        }
    });
```

step 1 screenshot:
[image]

step 2 screenshot: here only the uncheck row suppose to enable but all the row get enable
[image]

Comment: While I've edited your code for readability I have not corrected the syntax error in your HTML of `<tr class="hidden toggle advanced"">` the duplicated quote-marks need to be corrected, I left them because I don't know if that's *the* problem with your code, or just one of the problems with your code. Please do consider using an IDE.

Comment: Instead of `false == $(this).prop("checked")` you can write `!$(this).prop("checked")`, the prop(checked) returns a boolean, if you want the false to be true, just ! it

Comment: Please add your CSS as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this `'pointer-events':'none'` CSS to `td` it will make row disable except last td.

```js
 //select all checkboxes
    $("#chkNotCoveredIp").change(function () {  //"select all" change 
        $(".chkNotCovIp").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked")); //change all ".checkbox" checked status
        $(".clearValueIp").prop("disabled", false);
        $(".clearValueIp").val('');
        
        if( $(this).is(":checked") ){
            $(this).closest('table').find('td:not(:last-child)').css({'pointer-events':'none','background-color':'grey'});
         }else{
            $(this).closest('table').find('td:not(:last-child)').css({'pointer-events':'auto','background-color':'white'});
         }
        
    });

    //".checkbox" change 
    $('.chkNotCovIp').change(function () {
        //uncheck "select all", if one of the listed checkbox item is unchecked
        if (false == $(this).prop("checked")) { //if this item is unchecked
           
            $(".clearValueIp").prop("disabled", false); // 
        }
        //check "select all" if all checkbox items are checked
        if ($('.chkNotCovIp:checked').length == $('.chkNotCovIp').length) {
            $("#chkNotCoveredIp").prop('checked', true);
            $(".clearValueIp").prop("disabled", true);
        }
        
         if( $(this).is(":checked") ){
            $(this).closest('tr').find('td:not(:last-child)').css({'pointer-events':'none','background-color':'grey'});
         }else{
            $(this).closest('tr').find('td:not(:last-child)').css({'pointer-events':'auto','background-color':'white'});
         }
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <span class="chkBoxcls">
      <input id="chkboxIP" class="chkBoxPer" style="text-align: center" type="checkbox" name="checkBoxPercent" value="1">
    </span>
  </td>
  <td style="text-align:left" class="txtPer">
    <strong id="lbl1">Inpatient(IP)</strong><button class="btn btn-sm hide arrowNone"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
  </td>

  <td>
    <asp:TextBox id="IINTier1Ip" CssClass="TxtBox12 txtDataPopTier1 clearValueIp" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span15" runat="server" class="pers">%</span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="IINTier2Ip" CssClass="TxtBox12 txtDataPopTier2 clearValueIp" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span16" runat="server" class="pers">%</span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="OONIp" CssClass="TxtBox12 txtDataPopOON clearValueIp txtIpOon" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span17" runat="server" class="pers">%</span>
  </td>

  <td>
    <span class="chkBoxcls">
      <input id="chkNotCoveredIp" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CheckBox1" class="chkNotCovIp">
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="hidden toggle advanced"">
  <td>
    <span class="chkBoxcls">
      <input id="chkboxIpMedical" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CheckBox1">
    </span>
  </td>
  <td style="text-align:left"><span style="padding-left: 3%">IP Medical</span></td>
  <td>
    <asp:TextBox id="IINTier1IpMedical" CssClass="TxtBox12 txtDataPopTier1 clearValueIpMed clearValueIp" onInput="computeValue('#IINTier1IpMedical','#IINTier2IpMedical','#OONIpMedical')" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span18" runat="server" class="pers">%</span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="IINTier2IpMedical" CssClass="TxtBox12 txtDataPopTier2 clearValueIpMed clearValueIp" onInput="computeValue('#IINTier1IpMedical','#IINTier2IpMedical','#OONIpMedical')" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span19" runat="server" class="pers">%</span>
  </td>

  <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="OONIpMedical" CssClass="TxtBox12 txtDataPopOON clearValueIpMed txtIpOon clearValueIp" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span20" runat="server" class="pers">%</span>
  </td>

  <td>
    <span class="chkBoxcls">
      <input id="chkNotCoveredIpMedical" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CheckBox1" class="chkNotCovIp">
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="hidden toggle advanced">
  <td>
    <span class="chkBoxcls">
      <input id="chkboxIpSurgical" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CheckBox1">
    </span>
  </td>
  <td style="text-align:left"><span style="padding-left: 3%">IP Surgical</span> </td>
  <td>
    <asp:TextBox id="IINTier1IpSurgical" CssClass="TxtBox12 txtDataPopTier1 clearValueIpSur clearValueIp" onInput="computeValue('#IINTier1IpSurgical','#IINTier2IpSurgical','#OONIpSurgical')" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span21" runat="server" class="pers">%</span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="IINTier2IpSurgical" CssClass="TxtBox12 txtDataPopTier2 clearValueIpSur clearValueIp" onInput="computeValue('#IINTier1IpSurgical','#IINTier2IpSurgical','#OONIpSurgical')" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span22" runat="server" class="pers">%</span>
  </td>

  <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="OONIpSurgical" CssClass="TxtBox12 txtDataPopOON clearValueIpSur txtIpOon clearValueIp" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span23" runat="server" class="pers">%</span>
  </td>

  <td>
    <span class="chkBoxcls">
      <input id="chkNotCoveredIpSurgical" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CheckBox1" class="chkNotCovIp">
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="hidden toggle advanced">
  <td>
    <span class="chkBoxcls">
      <input id="chkboxIpMeternity" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CheckBox1">
    </span>
  </td>
  <td style="text-align:left"><span style="padding-left: 3%">IP Maternity</span> </td>
  <td>
    <asp:TextBox id="IINTier1IpMaternity" CssClass="TxtBox12 txtDataPopTier1 clearValueIpMet clearValueIp" onInput="computeValue('#IINTier1IpMaternity','#IINTier2IpMaternity','#OONIpMaternity')" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span24" runat="server" class="pers">%</span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="IINTier2IpMaternity" CssClass="TxtBox12 txtDataPopTier2 clearValueIpMet clearValueIp" onInput="computeValue('#IINTier1IpMaternity','#IINTier2IpMaternity','#OONIpMaternity')" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span25" runat="server" class="pers">%</span>
  </td>

  <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="OONIpMaternity" CssClass="TxtBox12 txtDataPopOON clearValueIpMet txtIpOon clearValueIp" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span26" runat="server" class="pers">%</span>
  </td>

  <td>
    <span class="chkBoxcls">
      <input id="chkNotCoveredIpMeternity" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CheckBox1" class="chkNotCovIp">
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="hidden toggle advanced">
  <td>
    <span class="chkBoxcls">
      <input id="chkboxIpMHSA" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CheckBox1">
    </span>
  </td>
  <td style="text-align:left"><span style="padding-left: 3%">IP MHSA</span></td>
  <td>
    <asp:TextBox id="IINTier1IpMHSA" CssClass="TxtBox12 txtDataPopTier1 clearValueIpMhsa clearValueIp" onInput="computeValue('#IINTier1IpMHSA','#IINTier2IpMHSA','#OONIpMHSA')" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span27" runat="server" class="pers">%</span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="IINTier2IpMHSA" CssClass="TxtBox12 txtDataPopTier2 clearValueIpMhsa clearValueIp" onInput="computeValue('#IINTier1IpMHSA','#IINTier2IpMHSA','#OONIpMHSA')" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span28" runat="server" class="pers">%</span>
  </td>

  <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="OONIpMHSA" CssClass="TxtBox12 txtDataPopOON clearValueIpMhsa txtIpOon clearValueIp" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span29" runat="server" class="pers">%</span>
  </td>

  <td>
    <span class="chkBoxcls">
      <input id="chkNotCoveredIpMHSA" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CheckBox1" class="chkNotCovIp">
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="hidden toggle advanced">
  <td>
    <span class="chkBoxcls">
      <input id="chkboxIpNICU" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CheckBox1">
    </span>
  </td>
  <td style="text-align:left"><span style="padding-left: 3%">IP NICU</span> </td>
  <td>
    <asp:TextBox id="IINTier1IpNICU" CssClass="TxtBox12 txtDataPopTier1 clearValueIpNicu clearValueIp" onInput="computeValue('#IINTier1IpNICU','#IINTier2IpNICU','#OONIpNICU')" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span30" runat="server" class="pers">%</span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="IINTier2IpNICU" CssClass="TxtBox12 txtDataPopTier2 clearValueIpNicu clearValueIp" onInput="computeValue('#IINTier1IpNICU','#IINTier2IpNICU','#OONIpNICU')" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span31" runat="server" class="pers">%</span>
  </td>

  <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="OONIpNICU" CssClass="TxtBox12 txtDataPopOON clearValueIpNicu txtIpOon clearValueIp" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><span id="Span32" runat="server" class="pers">%</span>
  </td>

  <td>
    <span class="chkBoxcls">
      <input id="chkNotCoveredIpNICU" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CheckBox1" class="chkNotCovIp">
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That doesn't disable anything. It just makes it so you can't use your mouse to do a thing. You can still use your keyboard (for instance, I can't click on a checkbox, but I can tab to it and check it that way). Also, disabled form fields are not submitted with a form post, so extra backend processing would be needed to check if the fields should be processed.

Answer (score 0):

By using var $row = $(this).closest("tr") easily can solve this issue.

```
//select all checkboxes
            $("#chkNotCoveredIp").change(function () {  //"select all" change 
                $(".chkNotCovIp").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked")); //change all ".checkbox" checked status
                $(".clearValueIp").prop("disabled", false);
                $(".clearValueIp").val('');
            });
    
            //".checkbox" change 
            $('.chkNotCovIp').change(function (e) {
                //uncheck "select all", if one of the listed checkbox item is unchecked
                if (!$(this).prop("checked")) { //if this item is unchecked
    
                    var $row = $(this).closest("tr");    // Find the row
                    $row.find(".clearValueIp").prop("disabled", false);
                } else {
                    var $row = $(this).closest("tr");    // Find the row
                    $row.find(".clearValueIp").prop("disabled", true);
                    $row.find(".clearValueIp").val('');
                }
                //check "select all" if all checkbox items are checked
                if ($('.chkNotCovIp:checked').length == $('.chkNotCovIp').length) {
                    $("#chkNotCoveredIp").prop('checked', true);
                    $(".clearValueIp").prop("disabled", true);
                    $(".clearValueIp").val('');
                }
            });
```